# When trying to use a static ifstream member and accompanying function, I get a linker error

Tags: c++, class, static, fstream

Assuming that if the error's spotted in the .o file that it's the linker's problem...

Anyway, I'm writing a program to organize the courses I want to take in college by outputting them into a nicely formatted HTML file.  To do this, I'm going to throw a bunch of objects of my Course class into a list (the data structure I picked, unless someone warns otherwise), organize them by course code, and output them to the aforementioned HTML file, placing horizontal line breaks between each different major/minor/etc.  At the top of each line-broken segment will be the name of the major, reading like;

> AMS (Applied Mathematics and Statistics)

Whenever the user enters the course code (just the three letters, not the number), I want the *class* to check whether the code is on a .txt I provide with the program.  Because if I'm going to have dozens of `Courses` in the end, why bloat my code with an `fstream` or a member function for each object?  So I figured using some `static` magic might be a good idea.  Then I get this error message, using g++;

(Sorry it looks messy, by the way, I'm not sure how to format this neatly here.)

> In function `std::basic_ifstream >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)':
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream| 528 | undefined reference to `Course::courses'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream|533|undefined reference to`Course::courses'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream|533|undefined reference to `Course::courses'
>   obj/Debug/main.o In function`std::basic_filebuf >::is_open() const':
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream|223|undefined reference to `Course::courses'
>   obj/Debug/main.oIn function`std::basic_ifstream >::close()':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream|566|undefined reference to `Course::courses'
>   obj/Debug/main.o:/usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream|529|more undefined references to`Course::courses' follow

I'm then directed to this segment of the fstream header;

```
void open(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
  {
if (!_M_filebuf.open(__s, __mode | ios_base::in))
  this->setstate(ios_base::failbit);
else
  // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
  // 409. Closing an fstream should clear error state
  this->clear();
  }
```

The two static members I have (open and close the stream, at the start and end of the whole collection process for the courses) as well as the member itself are declared like so;

```
class Course
{
    public:
        Course();
        void setup();
        bool confirm();
        stringstream entry;
        static void openCodeList() { courses.open("codes"); if (!courses.is_open()) exit(1); }
        static void closeCodeList() { courses.close(); }
    private:
        //Irrelevant strings and bits, etc, etc.
        static ifstream courses;
}
```

I do have other .cpp and .h files involved (namely a File class to handle actually outputting everything in the end), but I have not even mentioned these fstream-related members in any of them but my obviously WIP main.cpp;

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the Stony Brook Course Organizer!  This program will help you\n"
            "organize the courses that you wish to take at Stony Brook University.\n\n";
    Course thefirst;
    Course::openCodeList();
    thefirst.setup();
    thefirst.confirm();
    Course::closeCodeList();
}
```

Any help in dealing with my `static` issues and advice for the future (even if not directly related to that) would greatly be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a definition for `Course::courses` anywhere? (`static ifstream courses;` in the class body is just a declaration, you need a definition outside of the class body somewhere, e.g.(`std::ifstream Course::courses;`)

Comment: `courses` is the name of the ifstream that reads the list of majors at Stony Brook, so yes.  I probably should (and will) name it better.

Comment: And I don't understand what you mean by defining it in this context.  Would you mind explaining a bit?  (Damn, forgot about the Edit button.)

Comment: I wasn't in any way objecting to the name of the member.

Comment: No, but I consider now that it might cause confusion.  I just want to make sure everyone's on the same page here.  Oh, and those two functions I defined are inlined, so I don't need to define them in the main .cpp file.

Comment: For example in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939491/static-member-error-in-c

Comment: I don't quite get what that does.  Would you mind explaining it?  It involves pointers, I think, that much I can gather.

Comment: The pointer is not relevant to what I was asking. I am asking if you have a definition for `Course::courses` anywhere. You need one, it should appear at global namespace scope and look something like: `std::ifstream Course::courses;` but it could have an initializer. If you don't have one, this is your problem and you need to add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the static member in a source file of your program, outside of the class definition.

E.g. in a .cpp:

```
std::ifstream Course::courses;
```